# Principal angle and Euler form of cube root of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

The principal angles of the complex arguments are in the range $-\pi \le x\le \pi $.

If so why does the comlex number

$\omega =\frac{\left(-1-\sqrt{3}i\right)}{2}$ is represented by

## $e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}$ = $\cos\left(\frac{4\pi }{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{4\pi }{3}\right)$

where $\frac{4\pi }{3}$ is greater than $\pi $, instead of representing it as

## $e^{-\frac{2\pi }{3}}$ =$\cos\left(\frac{-2\pi }{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{-2\pi }{3}\right)$

Comment: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Answer (score 1):

Different textbooks and different authors will not follow the exact same conventions. Some authors will choose their angles in the range $0 \le x < 2\pi$, others in the range $-\pi < x \le \pi$. There might be other possibilities too.

The reason for lack of consistency is that the choice of convention for the principal angle is not mathematically very important. What is much more important is simply to recognize that the complex exponential function is periodic, with period $2 \pi i$, and therefore the collection of **all** Euler forms for $\omega$ can be written as
$$\omega = \exp\biggl(\frac{4}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr) = \cos\biggl(\frac{4}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr) + i \sin\biggl(\frac{4}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr)
$$ 
It can also be written as
$$\omega = \exp\biggl(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr) = \cos\biggl(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr) + i \sin\biggl(-\frac{2}{3}\pi i + 2 \pi i \, n\biggr)
$$ 
There is no difference of mathematical validity between these two forms. If there is a difference in popularity, perhaps it is because some people avoid minus signs and others prefer smaller numbers.

Comment: But I think when it comes to the concepts of the characteristics of the roots (which states that: the n-th roots of unity are all in Geometric Progression) considering the above complex number with the argument $\frac{4\pi }{3}$ is much more relevant than the other one. This makes me confused.

Comment: @HijazAslam: In the case of the 3rd roots of unity, which form the geometric progression $\omega$, $\omega^2$, there are multiple ways to express them by choosing angles in arithmetic progression. One way is to use the angles $4\pi/3$, $8\pi/3$. Another way is to use the angles $-2\pi/3,-4\pi/3$. Both are mathematically valid.

Comment: Alright, so does it depend upon the common ratio we consider for the progression?